# Is increased erosion due to flooding part of a negative feedback mechanism for global warming?

Tags: climate-change

I have read that alkaline rock dust added to the sea can increase algal growth and sequestration of CO2. Is this part of a natural negative feedback for global warming because a typical scenario for global warming is that warm air moves further north carrying more moisture than cooler times. We seem to be seeing this in the UK at the moment with frequent flooding and there will be associated erosion of soils. Also in mountainous areas melting glaciers expose rock and carry erosion to the sea. I am anticipating that if it is a feedback mechanism it will be too slow to deal with the rate we are adding greenhouse gases to the atmosphere, we will step over that oportunity?

Comment: Interesting question! It is true that, over long timescales, the natural warming is counterbalanced by the enhanced weathering of rocks in a warm climate, which puts carbon back down the oceans. See for instance these articles (and scientific papers linked therein):
https://www.gfz-potsdam.de/en/section/earth-surface-geochemistry/topics/co2-weathering-and-climate
https://www.washington.edu/news/2017/05/22/weathering-of-rocks-a-poor-regulator-of-global-temperatures/
https://phys.org/news/2023-08-chemical-weathering-solution-climate-crisis.html

Comment: A perfect answer,